# Getting syntax error while exporting mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, database, centos, cpanel

I have cPanel trial version installed on the centOS server which is expired now. So I don't have access to cPanel user and WHM login.

I am tried the following
`mysql> mysqldump -u root –ppassword  db_name > db_nametext.sql;`

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near mysqldump -u root –ppassword db_name > db_name at line 1
```

Thank you for time and consideration.

Comment: Space is missing between -p and password

Comment: @KrishnaVaddepalli, I have separated -p and password still getting same error.

Comment: You should run it from $ prompt not from the mysql prompt.

Try ```mysqldump -u root -p password db_name > db_nametext.sql``` from the user prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run `mysqldump` from `mysql` shell: `mysqldump` is not a SQL statement but an executable that must be run from linux shell like `mysql` command.

Comment: I am getting following error `mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '-password' when selecting the database`

Comment: Try to use the same command line when you run `mysql`.